# how to display a string from a rest webservice in windows forms?

Tags: c#, string, wcf, web-services, rest

how can display a string from a rest webservice in windows forms my xml looks like this:

```
<string>whatever</string>
```

How can you display that in a textbox in win forms?

If I try

```
        string uri = string.Format("etc/{0}/{1} Sad.Text, Happy.Text");
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uri);
        string mystring = xDoc.Element("String").Value;
        textBox1.Text = mystring;
```

You get an object reference error?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689303/consuming-a-rest-xml-web-service

Comment: @V4Vendetta you could almost make that an answer

Comment: hahaha... yeah looks strangely at the ceiling :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML elements are case-sensitive.  Try,

```
string mystring = xDoc.Element("string").Value;
```

---

A better way to solve the problem is to not use XML to return a simple string.  The media type `text/plain` is designed to do that.  If you are using [Microsoft's ASP.NET Web API](http://nuget.org/packages/AspNetWebApi) just return

```
return new HttpResponseMessage() { 
            Content = new StringContent("etc/{0}/{1} Sad.Text, Happy.Text")
           };
```

and on the client (using this http://nuget.org/Packages/system.net.http)  do,

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
textBox1.Text = httpClient.GetAsync(uri).Result.Content.ReadAsString();
```

Comment: seriously haha microsoft needs to fix the damm case sensitive stuff!

Comment: @KirstyWhite  You are going to have to complain much higher up the food chain than Microsoft.  The XML specification defines element and attribute names as case sensitive.

Comment: @KirstyWhite who says its broken?

Answer (score -2):

I would use XmlSerializer to get the information out of XML returned by the web service. I am assuming that your XML is just in a string. You could do something like this for your simple example, but this would also work for more complex objects returned by a REST web service.

```
 XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer ( typeof ( string ) );
 MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(StringToUTF8ByteArray(restResult));
 XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
 string textBoxVal = xs.Deserialize(memoryStream);
```

Comment: that seems really heavy just to get a string of text?

Comment: then maybe you need only `stream` `.ReadToEnd()` and then ignore the tags :)

Comment: My proposed solution is generic for any xml returned. If you do not want to use the XmlSerializer and you always just have that string returned you could just pull it out of the string using Substring since you know how long the tag is in the beginning and end of the string.